# The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context X to COM context Y for 60 seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, memory-management

I got this frequently error on my application that takes the sound as byte from microphone  to stored in the soundfile (.wav).

**""The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x686670 to COM context 0x686898 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.""**

What is the mainly cause of this error?

Why is this error mainly occurs?

What is the solution for this type of error??

Does this error leads to "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"??

And how is this "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" error occured too??

Thanx in advance.